# Antonym for verbal diarrhea

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The act of speaking excessively or continuously is referred to as verbal diarrhea. How about speaking very little? Is there a word for it?

Comment: There's a common antonym for _diarrhea_; why not use that?

Comment: [laconism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/laconic)

Comment: Perhaps not the most common of words (had to check the dictionary to confirm that it was actually a commonly accepted one at all), but I quite like the sound of ***taciturnity***.

Comment: How about 'verbal retention'?

Comment: OP's *verbal diarrhea* is of course a whimsical slang term for [***logorrhea***](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=HrOgUp_pMcX_ygPYuYDIAg#q=logorrhea%20definition) *- pathologically excessive and often incoherent talkativeness or wordiness.*

Comment: The most appropriate answer would be "Yes.", but the site won't let you do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a (possibly periphrastic) term with negative nuance then *verbal constipation* sounds appropriate.

An opposite term though of *verbal diarrhea*, which most often is used as a virtue is laconicism. (From the greek word λακωνικός=laconic, which originates from Laconia, the ancient greek state with capital Sparta, where it was considered a virtue to express yourself using a mimimal amount of words.)

Answer (score 7):

A good term to describe the person who speaks little (as opposed to the act itself of remaining silent) is *[taciturn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taciturn)*.

Many other words that describe people who tend to be quiet imply their reasons for not being talkative--for instance, *[reticent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reticent)*, *[diffident](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diffident)*, and *[aloof](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aloof)*. *Taciturn* has relatively little nuance in that respect.

Comment: I've seen *taciturn* used with a clear connotation that the person is a grumpy, cold person - that is, implying that it's part of their disposition, as opposed to just their current behavior. That said, I think taciturn is still the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking for an adjective (rather than the act or the speech itself), then *terse* would work well.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **[parsimony](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=parsimony)**

> excessive unwillingness to spend money or use resources; stinginess

The term is sometimes used in the phrase *[verbal parsimony](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=parsimony)*.

And there is always **[sphinx-like](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sphinx-like)**

> mysterious and not allowing people to know what you are thinking

Answer (score 1):

I'm **[close lipped](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/close+lipped)** myself. Some would say **[tight lipped](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tight-lipped)**:

> 2:  reluctant to speak :  taciturn

Answer (score 0):

As John says, verbal constipation would seem suitable (and witty). More fun, but sadly less suitable, might be [verbal charley horse](http://thesaurus.com/browse/constipation).

Answer (score 0):

"Succinct": using few words to state or express an idea

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succinct